# Getting TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' when client starts

Tags: python, sockets, typeerror

So when I run the client module, terminal sends back an error: "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'". I encoded the message sent by the client so i'm not sure what is wrong. Any help on figuring out the problem would be appreciated!

Here's my client.py:

```
import socket


def client_program():
    host = socket.gethostname()
    port = 5000

    client_socket = socket.socket()
    client_socket.connect((host, port))

    message = input(" -> ")

while message.lower().strip() != 'bye':
    client_socket.send(message.encode())
    data = client_socket.recv(1024).decode()

    print('Received from server: ' + data)

    message = input(" -> ")

client_socket.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    client_program()
```

Here's my server.py:

```
import socket
import sys
from _thread import start_new_thread


HOST = ''
PORT = 5000
try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
except socket.error as msg:
    print("Could not create socket. Error Code: ", str(msg[0]), "Error: ", msg[1])
    sys.exit(0)

print("[-] Socket Created")

try:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    print("[-] Socket Bound to port " + str(PORT))
except socket.error as msg:
    print("Bind Failed. Error Code: {} Error: {}".format(str(msg[0]), msg[1]))
    sys.exit()

s.listen(10)
print("Listening...")
```

def client_thread(conn):
    conn.send("Welcome to the Server. Type messages and press enter to send.\n")

```
while True:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    if not data:
        break
    reply = "OK . . " + data
    conn.sendall(reply)
conn.close()


while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print("[-] Connected to " + addr[0] + ":" + str(addr[1]))

    start_new_thread(client_thread, (conn,))

s.close()
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full traceback.

Comment: * I encoded the message sent by the client*. No you only did that before the loop, but not inside the loop. Close to a typo...

Comment: I actually made a typo in my post. The error happens when I start the client server and i'm actually never able to enter an input before it happens.